# On click of Link, set HREF as cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to use cookies to check if a user has already clicked a link. My logic is when a user clicks link, it's href is set as a cookie.

My original code worked fine for one link but I need to set a cookie for any link that is clicked.

```
    $( ".present a" ).click(function() {
     var haveCookie = $(this).attr('href');
     $.cookie(haveCookie, true);
    });
```

The code below is more along the lines of my logic but cookie is not being set, is there and error with code below?

```
    $( ".present a" ).click(function() {
       $.cookie((this).attr('href'), true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you just be missing a $, in $(this)?

```
$( ".present a" ).click(function() {
   $.cookie($(this).attr('href'), true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gn3f86mb/

Comment: hehe, didn't see it at first eather